# Anchor links and form action to current page but with addition GET values in the URL

Tags: html, apache, hyperlink, anchor

On a page called `somepage.php`, I have the following HTML.  I might be changing the name of the file, so I would rather not hardcode `somepage.php` in the links and action attributes.  I could do so serverside using PHP, but I do not wish to.  The site is limited to a very select audience, and I am okay with a JavaScript/jQuery solution which doesn't degrade (assuming it requires little code to maintain) or some feature that is only available to modern browsers.  I might be open to an Apache solution, however, this is a last choice.

Is this possible, and if so, how is it implemented?

**EDIT.  I don't think I was clear.  How could I modify the below code so that functionality is identical, however, it doesn't include "somepage.php" in any of the anchor or form attributes.**

```
<form action="somepage.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" value="controller_1" name="controller" />
 <!-- other stuff -->
</form>

<form action="somepage.php?controller=controller_2" method="post">
 <!-- other stuff -->
</form>

<a href="somepage.php?controller=controller_3">foo</a></li>


<a href="somepage.php?controller=controller_4&amp;bla=blabla">bar</a></li>
```

Comment: @Verhaeren.  Maybe.  Is this possible?

Comment: Understood.  But how would I use this to make links on a page to point to the current page?  Would I need to include an onclick attribute for each page which uses inline JS to redirect?